# Using "array_values" with "foreach" data?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to organize an array of data to be sent in an email. I have no problem getting the data, but I am not sure how to organize it.

**Foreach:** *Here outputs a list of questions generated by the user in the backend*

```
$message = array();

foreach($questions['questions'] as $key => $value){   
       if(is_array($value) && isset($value[ 'questionlist'])){
           foreach($value as $key => $subquestion){ //line 119
               foreach ($subquestion as $key => $value){
                   $message[] = $value['a-question'];                           
               }
           }
       }                     
   }
```

I am trying to conjoin the data with each other, the data from the foreach and the `$_POST` data which is check values.

My logic for doing it this way is because one comes from the database, one is just form data (that does not need to be saved to the database it comes from the front end unlike the data from the database that is generated via backend) That said there perhaps is a better way, but I pretty much got this I am just not sure how to join the data so it looks like

```
    <li>MYARRAYDATA - MYFORMDATA</li>
    <li>MYARRAYDATA - MYFORMDATA</li>
    <li>MYARRAYDATA - MYFORMDATA</li>



    //The form input data '0', '1' values
    $checks = $_POST['personalization_result'];

    //Putting that data into array_values
    $checkValues = array_values($checks);    

    //Then passing the array_values into 'implode' and organizing it with a list (<li>)
    $checkString = '<li>'.implode('</li><li>',$checkValues).'</li>';

    //Then testing with var_dump outputs a nice list of '0','1' values
    var_dump ($checkString);
```

Trying the same method but trying to conjoin the `foreach` array and the check values does not work, here is an example.

```
    //Similar to $checkValues I pass the data from the foreach into "array_values"
    var_dumping this works fine.
    $arrayValues = array_values($message);

    //This is obvious it's the same as above it "implodes" the data nicely into a list(<li>)       
    $arrayString = '<li>'.implode('</li><li>',$arrayValues).'</li>';

    //This var dumps the "$arrayString" nicely
    var_dump ($arrayString)
```

Again the actual question is here, how do I conjoin each piece of data?

**My Attempts:** *Here are my attempts for "conjoining" the data.*

```
    // This does not work well (maybe by cleaning up it can work) but it outputs 2 separate lists
    var_dump ($arrayString.'_'.$checkString);

    //I tried to run it inside one implode variable this is invalid arguments
    $checkString = '<li>'.implode('</li><li>',$arrayValues.'_'.$checkValues).'</li>';

    //Modified one implode variable this outputs see below 
    $checkString = '<li>'.implode('</li>'.$arrayValues.'<li>',$checkValues).'</li>';

    <li>Array
    1</li>
    <li>Array
    0</li>
    <li>Array
    1</li>
    <li>Array
    0</li>
```

**var_dump results:** *Here is the var_dump result of each array, I want to combine these into one list*

$_POST array

```
// Var dump of form $_POST DATA
var_dump ($checkString);

//Result
    1      //This is generated through the $_POST method not on database
    0      //This is generated through the $_POST method not on database
    1      //This is generated through the $_POST method not on database
    0      //This is generated through the $_POST method not on database
```

DATABASE array

```
// Var dump of datbase generated from backend
var_dump ($arrayString);

//Result 
    I am 1         //This is generated in the backend and is stored on a database
    Hi I am 2      //This is generated in the backend and is stored on a database
    civil is 3     //This is generated in the backend and is stored on a database
    THIS IS FOURTA //This is generated in the backend and is stored on a database
```

The Goal

```
     I am 1         - 1 //This is checked
     Hi I am 2      - 0 //This is NOT checked
     civil is 3     - 1 //This is checked
     THIS IS FOURTA - 0 //This is NOT checked
```

[image: stuff]

**The Answer:** *Thanks to @xdim222*

I didn't understand it at first, because of the increment, but now I understand it all, initially it would have worked but my variables were under the foreach statement and that was causing it not to return the array.

At least in my opinion thats what it was, because when I added the variable above the foreach it worked.

I modified the answer to suit my code.

```
    //$messages = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');
    //Instead of using this array I used the array generated in my foreach above.

    // Instead of this $checks = array(1,0,1,0); I take the $_POST value which generates an array, you can see above.
    $checkValues = array_values($checks);

    $checkString = implode($checkValues);

    $i=0;
    foreach($messages as $msg) {
        echo $msg . ' - ' . ( isset($checkString[$i])? $checkString[$i] : 0 ) . '<br>';
    $i++;
    }
```

Again thanks to *@xdim222* for being patient, reading my long question, and most importantly helping me learn, by asking this question and finding a solution this stuff really sticks and is in my opinion the best way to learn (by asking). :)

Comment: I know it looks long but asking this question really helped me narrow down to what I need specifically, this is long just because I am sharing code. I simply just want to nicely join the two pieces of data. The `foreach` data is a question and the `$_POST` data is from the form and has the result if it was checked or not, so I am trying to join the question with '0', or '1' if its been checked or not.

Comment: have read 3 times from top to bottom, still struggling in understanding what you want to join together. Are you trying to list all questions including sub questions with an extra field to indicates if each question is checked by the user or not ?

Comment: `$message[]` inside the foreach is an array of data from the data base I am passing that through `array_values` then `imploding` then I do the exact same with form data `$checks = $_POST['personalization_result'];` I have two separate pieces of data one a string of text(database data) one a numeric value based on if the input was checked 0,1

Comment: Yeah im trying to match the question with the value if it has been checked.. its just that the question is stored in a DB the checked value I dont want into a DB it comes from the front end using $_POST..  its all there I just cant conjoin them

Comment: Does my question not make sense to anyone? Don't over think it, im just trying to format the email so it displays the two pieces of data.

Comment: It should be a simple problem, but somehow you make it quite complicated (sorry for being honest :) )..
So, what you have here is 2 arrays:
1. $checks
2. $message
And you want to display it side-by-side? May I know what's the purpose? Is there any relation between those 2 arrays? My questions here may lead to the real solution of your problem.

Comment: Yes, no thank you for being honest but it's not offensive so no need to apologize, it just looks complicated because I am being very detailed in the question. But I keep saying the question is just trying to format the two arrays in A B format DATABASE_ARRAY FORM_POST ARRAY.. If I may be honest, by asking these questions in detail I learn much better, and a lot of times I end up not asking a question because I find the solution while writing, this question started off as something different then by asking and writing I made sense of a lot. I just dont know how to format the array.

Comment: I updated the OP that should clear things up.

Comment: Hi Mike, just a quick comment, I think you don't need $checkString, use $checkValues instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easier, I assign $messages and $checks directly, I have tried this code and it works. You might have different elements of your arrays, but I think you can figure it out from my code below:

```
  $messages = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');

  $checks = array(1,0,1,0);

  $i=0;
  foreach($messages as $msg) {
    echo $msg . ' - ' . ( isset($checks[$i])? $checks[$i] : 0 ) . '<br>';
    $i++;
  }
```

PS: I made a mistake in my previous answer by incrementing $i before echoing things out, array element should start by 0.

Comment: Yeah I see what you're doing now, I had to put the `$checkString` variable above the foreach, it wouldnt work when it was below. Also that being said, I used the `$checkString` in place of $checks. I am still trying to wrap my head around the increment, if you have time could you help explain? Here is what I think, the `$i` matches the arrays so `$checks[$i]` pulls the array to match the amount of `$msg` if there is 20 `$msg` then the last `$checks[20]` which would pull the last check in the array? Correct, I understand the increment now I think. BTW thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for your reply to my comment above, I'm trying to write some code here..

I assume you want to display the questions that were pulled from database and it should be displayed based on what user chose in the form. So you may use this code:

```
foreach($questions['questions'] as $key => $value){   
   if(is_array($value) && isset($value[ 'questionlist'])){
       foreach($value as $key => $subquestion){ //line 119
           foreach ($subquestion as $key => $value){
               $message[$key] = $value['a-question'];                           
           }
       }
   }
```

}

I added $key in $message in the code above, with an assumption that $key is the index of a question, and this index will be matched with what user chose in the form. Then we can list all the questions that a user have chosen:

```
foreach($checks as $check) 
  echo '<li>'.$check . ' - ' . $message[$check].'</li>';
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes the logic is correct, nothing spectacular just simply matching data, from what I have getting and displaying data is not a problem but matching them is where I am clueless... Your code looks great, and I am sure it will work (thanks for putting effort) I am going to implement it and post back ASAP!!

Comment: This is very close but seems a bit backwards. 
1 - Hi I am 2...
0 - I am 1...
1 - Hi I am 2...
0 - I am 1...

There are only two form values 0,1.. but there are a limitless amount of questions right now for testing I have 4 questions... the result of the above code is looping two questions starting with the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update:

```
$i=0; 
foreach($message as $msg) {
  $i++;
  echo '<li>'. $msg . ' - ' . ( isset($checks[$i])? $checks[$i] : 0 ) . '</li>';
}
```

Maybe this is what you want.

As I said, there should be a relation between the $message and $checks, otherwise the above code looks a bit weird, because how do we know that a question is selected by user? Maybe you should show how you get that $_POST['personalization_result'] in your HTML.

Comment: Again appreciate the help let me check it out. :)

Comment: The $_POST comes from `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` a submit button, this takes the value of the input there is one hidden input with value 0, the visable input has value 1, when the form is submitted the data is stored in $_SESSION and its also emailed to the admin

Comment: The problem with this answer using an increment doesnt make sense to me, I am not trying to get 1,2,3,4.. but 0,1,0,1

Comment: You can change $checks to $checkValues

Comment: I realized I have some tweaking to do to the form inputs, I coded it as a static form then turned it into a PHP form looping the inputs, and found a few errors, I am going to spend time tweaking them then try this answer, I am sure once I tweak that out this will work.. Ill keep you updated :)

Comment: Ok I was saving it with ajax, and used a method to save $_POST to a database via ajax(by accident added it in testing phase, but depreciated it), throwing my PHP off, now that I have removed the ajax function I should be able to implement your method better.. lets give it a crack!

Comment: I updated the OP with the results... red and green should match up.. your code in blue out puts all zeros, due to the increment.. there shouldn't be an increment the array increments itself `$checks = $_POST['personalization_result'];` is an array.. I wrote the code so that there is a loop for every question and within the loop is the input check boxes, so for every question there will be the exact same amount of results in the exact same order...